# Problem with media queries. Class and id don't work in media queries

Tags: html, css, class, media-queries

```css
body{
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 15px;
        }
        .main{
            background-color: pink;
            width:80%;
            float:left;
            max-width: 53em;
        }
        ul{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
        }
        article{
            padding: 3em;
        }

        
        nav a{
            display: block;
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: .3em;
            background-color: gold;
            -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
            box-sizing:border-box;
        }
        nav a:hover{
            background-color: pink;
        }
        nav{
            margin:0;
            width:20%;
            float: left;
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        .container{
            max-width: 60%;
            margin: 2em auto;
        }
        figure{
            margin:0;
        }
        article img{
            width:100%;
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 66em){

            .container{
                width:90%;
            }
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 53em){
            nav{
                float:none;
                width: 100%;
            }
            nav a{
                float:left;
                width: 20%;
                padding: 1em;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .main{
                float: none;
                width:100%;
            }
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 32em){
            .container{
                width:100%;
                margin:0;
            }
            article{
                padding: 1em;
            }
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 20em){
                body{
                    margin:0;
                    padding: 0;
                }
                nav a{
                float:none;
                width: auto;
                padding: 0.3em;
                }
        }
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
    <title>Responsive design</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='container'>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="?page=1">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="?page=2">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="?page=3">Three</a></li>
                <li><a href="?page=4">Four</a></li>
                <li><a href="?page=5">Five</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
```

I am writing because my media queries doesn't work. Actually, classes and id's don't work. What could I do? This code is only exercise, but I want to know, why it isn't working. On the top and bottom are tags html and DOCTYPE html, but it doesn't matter. I wrote this right. The same with the rest of body.

Comment: Your media queries are working. But it seems to me that you confused the construction of the menu on a desktop with a mobile one.

Comment: [Doesn't work isn't a useful description of the problem](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mcve] (your code is hardly minimal, reduce it so it has the least amount of code needed to demonstrate the problem). Make use the live demo feature of the question editor.

Comment: In my opinion, my problem is not that media queries isn't working because normal tag for example nav a or other like that is working, but when i want change width:100%; in .container in media for max-width: 32 em. It doesn't change on my page.

Comment: I add so much code, because maybe i make a mistake in another section of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have enough reputation to comment on posts yet, but I can see why you are not getting the expected result once you set .container to 100% in 32em media query. It is because you have .container max-width set up to 60%. Try adding max-width:100%, like below:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 32em){
        .container{
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            max-width: 100%;
        }
        article{
            padding: 1em;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is working now :D. I will look at this next time.